# Javascript onclick needs 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Each div is shown only after 2 clicks at the start.After 2 initial clicks on each div, each div showhide works with just 1 click. Javascript and html

```js
function showhide() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('search_form')[0];
  if (div.style.display == "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function showhide2() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0];
  if (div.style.display == "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function showhide3() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('carrello')[0];
  if (div.style.display == "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.search_form {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}

.login {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}

.carrello {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-carrello">
  <img src="img.png" onClick="showhide();" onmouseover="this.src='img.png'" onmouseout="this.src='gg.png'" width="50px" height="50px"> &nbsp &nbsp
  <img src="img.png" onClick="showhide2()" onmouseover="this.src='img.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img.png'" width="50px" height="50px">
  <img src="imgt.png" onClick="showhide3()" onmouseover="this.src='img.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img.png'" width="50px" height="50px">
</div>
```

are both in a single PHP page.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WesFoster why does he need a class attribute for each image?

Comment: The snippet you've provided throws an error every time one clicks on any of the images. Please update your question with a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the display property is not actually set (although it is applied through CSS), it's initial value is empty (and thus not equal to `'none'` ).
If checked in the reverse order, it would work, but perhaps safer is to use an extra class (with the display property) you toggle instead.
A minimized example:

```js
function showhide(cn) {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName(cn)[0];
  div.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.login-carrello >img{
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.search_form,.login, .carrello {  
  float: right;  
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-carrello">
  <img src="/wp-content/themes/kyro/img/search.png" onClick="showhide('search_form')">
  <img src="img.png" onClick="showhide('login')">
  <img src="imgt.png" onClick="showhide('carrello')">  
</div>

<div class="search_form">search_form</div>
<div class="login">login</div>
<div class="carrello">carrello</div>
```

The start setting for `.search_form,.login, .carrello` is `display:none`, but adding `.show` overrides that. (I've also taken the liberty of parameterizing the classname to show/hide so only a single function is needed. With late binding it could be automated further, but this stays pretty close to the original)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in JavaScript code. Since display property was initially set in css, `div.style.display` won't give you `none`. So, you have to change your code a little bit. Like this:

```
if(div.style.display != "block")
   div.style.display = "block";
else
   div.style.display = "none";
```

Once you set the display property using JavaScript code, you can read it using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you're looking for a double click, or just two seperate clicks. However if a double click would satisfy your functionality requirement, you could try something like the following:

```
<img src="img.png" ondblclick="showhide2()" onmouseover="this.src='img.png'" mouseout="this.src='img.png'" width="50px" height="50px">
```